# Using IN with a range of values?

Tags: t-sql

I have an attribute
earlier it could only have one fixed value.

`Where xAttribute = fixedValue`

But now it could be in a range of values,
I know I can use the **IN** operator

But How can I return/get the range of values?

I don't think I can use a table value function with IN?

`WHERE xAttribute IN (myTableValueFunc())`
 
or to make this actually work,

`WHERE xAttribute IN (Select Id from myTableValueFunc())`

Is there an another or a, *better* way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table-valued function returns a table, then you can join with it...

**Sample data**

```
CREATE FUNCTION myTableValueFunc()  
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN
    -- implement your function
    SELECT x.Id
    FROM (values (100), (200), (300)) x(Id);

create table SomeTable
(
  SomeField nvarchar(1),
  xAttribute int
);

insert into SomeTable (SomeField, xAttribute) values
('A', 100),
('B', 200),
('C', 300),
('D', 400),
('E', 500);
```

**Solution**

```
select st.SomeField, st.xAttribute
from SomeTable st
join myTableValueFunc() mtvf
  on mtvf.Id = st.xAttribute;
```

**Result**

```
SomeField xAttribute
--------- ----------
A         100
B         200
C         300
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=fc878c44eb32063c9d4a96d9388b1138) to see things in action.